# Ajax POST variables and refresh div on type

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquerymobile webapp I'm working on and I have a div that is updating from a $.POST command but it's not sending the variable properly.  Help is apprecaited.

```
<div id="listing">
 <script>
 $.post('/ajax/listing',{lat:124125},
 function(data){        
                $('#listing').append(data).trigger('create');
                },'html')
</script>
/</div>
```

I'm trying to send the "lat" variable to /ajax/listing...which is set to wait for this variable to be POSTed.

Comment: what do you mean by not sending the var properly

Comment: Sorry I mean the page wasn't not receiving the POST variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :[Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)

post data here

```
 $.post(postUrl, { lat: "124125" }, function (result) {                     $("#listing").html(result);                 }                 );
```

or

Suggestion cna you use .Ajax() function of jquery which give you more  control on ajax request

```
$.ajax(
     {   type: "POST",   
         url: "some.php",   
          data: "name=John&location=Boston" 
   }).done(function( msg ) {   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); });
```

Comment: The alert is saying that my variable is still not set.

Comment: Ok, I got both solutions working.  Which lends itself better to updating when a variable updates or changes?

Comment: @John Brooks Pounders - k ...if possible accepte and upvote answer if it works for you

Comment: Followup question...shouldn't 'code' $.post('/ajax/listing',{lat:"$("#single").val()",lng:"-86.73947369999999"}, 'code'

Shouldn't this function then have my input of the name #single?

Comment: @John Brooks Pounders -  i think remove " and its should be lat:$("#single").val(),

Answer (score 1):

Change your data to a string.

```
$.post('/ajax/listing',{lat:"124125"},
```